# How to (i) add transition to jQuery Slider and (ii) make the slider responsive?

Tags: jquery, css, html, slider

I made this jQuery slider for a project that I am working on. Please refer this link for the same : https://jsfiddle.net/ag_dhruv/wq16ks86/1/

I have used the jQuery `animate` function to change the `left` property of the images. By doing this, I am able to achieve a minimal slider, without any transition effects.

Here are my questions regarding the slider :
**1) Is this the best way I can make a slider?**
**2) How can I add subtle transition effects while moving the images like fade-in or any other effect?**
**3) On resizing the page, my container resizes well (as it has set `width:80%`). But the images do not resize accordingly. How can I achieve that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to resize the image, you should add max-width to your image.

Here is the solution for question 2 and 3:

https://jsfiddle.net/wq16ks86/4/

the css solution is:

```
.first .slidercontainer img {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 100%;
    animation: fadein 2s infinite;
} 

@keyframes fadein {
    0%   { opacity: 0; }
    50% {opacity: 0.5;}
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Of course you should complement your css rules to be compatible in other browsers, too.